# Android: Is there a better way to create this View that has two States?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a view with two states - it has a 'ready' state and the 'pressed' state.

The way it is currently implemented seems inefficient. Both states of the button are coded into the layout as follows:

```
<!-- 'ready' state button -->
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/strut_button_1"
            style="@style/StrutButton" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/strut_1_badge"
                style="@style/Strut1Badge"
                android:text="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/strut_1_value"
                style="@style/StrutValue"
                android:text="@string/placeholder_text_short" />

        </RelativeLayout>

<!-- 'pressed' state button -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/strut_button_1_complete"
            style="@style/StrutButtonComplete"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/strut_1_badge"
                style="@style/Strut1Badge"
                android:text="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/strut_1_value"
                style="@style/StrutValueComplete"
                android:text="@string/placeholder_text_short" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/CheckMark"
                android:text="\u2714"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"  />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

I set up some handlers to toggle the visibility of the buttons. When the 'ready' state button is pressed, it turns its visibility to GONE, and it turns the visibility of the 'pressed' state button to SHOW.

I considered using a selector for the buttons, but the selector didn't seem capable of rendering the button layout I need.  Is there a better way to do this than what I currently have?

Comment: Why not toggle only the Checkmark visibility? It's the only thing that changes...

Answer (score 0):

Try using an XML drawable that sets the states:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/color_radio_selected" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/color_radio_selected" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/color_radio_selected" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/color_radio_selected" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/color_radio_unselected"/>

</selector>
```

The above sets the state of a radio button to selected for any of the pressed/focus states

Then, you can specify this button as the background of a button like this:

```
<RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_network"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/menu_background"
        android:button="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/color_radio_button   <!--    HERE --!>
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="14dp"
        android:text="@string/network"
        android:textColor="@drawable/menu_button_text_white"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to use a Button to set up a button and not TextViews. They are simpler to use since you are actually making a button. You can customise the appearance of it via a background image.

You could set different states in Java code. You could first implement View.OnTouchListener in your activity and set up an OnTouchListener like this:

```
button.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

Then in the OnTouchListener,

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        switch (v.getId()){
            case (R.id.yourbuttonid):
                //This code changes the background of the Button 
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pressed_state)
                break;
        }
    }else if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case (R.id.yourbuttonid):
                //This code changes the background of the Button
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ready_state)
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

In the above code, we set up what will happen when the button is pressed (ACTION_DOWN) and when it is left after pressing it (ACTION_UP). Before the button is pressed, the button will be as it is coded in the xml.

This code can even be used for different Buttons. Just add another case after the break; in the switch.

Hope this helped!!

Comment: the problem with explicitly setting background in your java is that if your code gets into a different state, your button's background may also be in a state you don't want.  Setting the background only for touch events MotionEvent ACTION_DOWN or MotionEvent.ACTION_UP means that any other state (i.e. MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL or MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) has a state that you may not wish to.          Letting the Android system paint your background using XML and pressed/focus states leaves your java code cleaner and without unwanted states to code for.

Comment: Actually, if you perform ACTION_MOVE, the Java code has a state for being pressed therefore that will take place and if the finger is moved from one point to another, then nothing will happen. I myself have used this code and it runs fine. Or he could just copy the same line of setBackgroundResource for pressed state and add it to ACTION_MOVE.